# Install Ubuntu on Unallocated Space after E Drive?

Tags: dual-boot

I want to dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu, I already have win 7 installed in C drive

The question is can i install Ubuntu on Unallocated space after the E drive?
i mean this space is not behind C drive.

Will it Dual boot? is there any risk on the drives before the Unallocated Space?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , there should be no problem with it. I have done the same on my laptop.